# Coffeescript is not being compiled correctly in rails with async and await syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-5, asset-pipeline

i have a similar coffee-script like this in my `assets/javascript` directory

```
#COFFEE SCRIPT CODE
class TestClass
  speak: ()->
    response = await fetch(location.url)
    console.log(response)
```

its being compiled correctly with proper `async/await` syntax in [coffee-script's official playground](https://coffeescript.org/#try:class%20TestClass%0A%20%20speak%3A%20()-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20response%20%3D%20await%20fetch(location.url)%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(response)%0A%20%20%20%20)

```
# COMPILED JS FROM COFFEESCRIPT OFFICIAL PLAYGROUND
var TestClass;

TestClass = class TestClass {
  async speak() {
    var response;
    response = (await fetch(location.url));
    return console.log(response);
  }

};
```

but when i write this in a file and make it compile through  assets pipeline it get compiled incorrectly

```
# COMPILED JS FROM COFFEESCRIPT ASSESTS PIPELINE
TestClass = (function() {
    function TestClass() {}

    TestClass.prototype.speak = function() {
      var response;
      response = await(fetch(location.url));
      return console.log(response);
    };

    return TestClass;

  })();
```

i am on **rails v5.2** and **ruby v2.6.4** on **macOS v10.14**

```
$ bundle info coffee-script
      * coffee-script (2.4.1)
            Summary: Ruby CoffeeScript Compiler
            Homepage: http://github.com/josh/ruby-coffee-script
            Path: /Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4/gems/coffee-script-2.4.1
```

[my gemlock file](https://pastebin.com/QpLHMveA)

why is this happening and how to fix it.

i need the proper async/await syntax via my assests pipeline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the `coffee-rails` gem doesn't use the most up-to-date version of CoffeeScript and is thus missing some of the ES2017 features like `await` that you're looking for.

`coffee-rails` itself depends on the [`coffee-script-source`](https://github.com/jessedoyle/coffee-script-source) gem which you [can see](https://github.com/jessedoyle/coffee-script-source/blob/master/src/js/coffee-script.js) is *still* using CoffeeScript v1.12.6:

```
# https://github.com/jessedoyle/coffee-script-source/blob/master/src/js/coffee-script.js

/**
 * CoffeeScript Compiler v1.12.6
 * http://coffeescript.org
 *
 * Copyright 2011, Jeremy Ashkenas
 * Released under the MIT License
 */
```

Comment: So there is no workaround for it ? Shoot i have to use the old syntax

Comment: I haven't tried myself, but the bottom of this thread has some info on getting CoffeeScript 2 working: https://github.com/rails/ruby-coffee-script/pull/23

Answer (score 1):

The `coffee-script-source` gem is out of date. It is suggested to use `webpacker` instead of the asset pipeline for newer js setups. But that could be a large restructure.

---

#### Workaround

There was a [pull request](https://github.com/rails/ruby-coffee-script/pull/24/commits/ad0e8be1f4238472d92f1cc2819d1f5a2e7180e5) suggesting a workaround to use coffeescript 2 :

> you *can* use this library with other versions of CoffeeScript by setting the `COFFEESCRIPT_SOURCE_PATH` environment variable, but we recommend using WebPacker for CoffeeScript 2 and up.
>
> ```
> export COFFEESCRIPT_SOURCE_PATH=/path/to/coffee-script/extras/coffee-script.js
> ```

You will need to install & locate your coffee-script 2 executable (if globally it would be found with `which coffee`, and if locally with `npm`, it would  be `./node_modules/.bin/coffee`). I'm not sure if your gem will include the correct coffee-script version, so I would suggest using npm or another node package manager instead.

---

### On Heroku

How to run on heroku based on this [Github comment](https://github.com/rails/ruby-coffee-script/pull/23#issuecomment-391955599)

1. Download and save the [standalone coffeescript compiler](https://coffeescript.org/v2/browser-compiler-modern/coffeescript.js) in your rails project (eg. make a new directory in the project root called `tools`
2. Set the env var for heroku so the coffee-script-source gem uses the correct compiler:

   heroku config:set COFFEESCRIPT_SOURCE_PATH=/app/tools/coffeescript.js

(usually `/app` is the project directory on heroku, but you may have to change this)

Comment: is it stable enough to be deployed in production ? if so how make it work on heroku ?

Comment: @NijeeshJoshy As it's compiled into JS, there will be no effect on production. You might need to look into browser support as coffeescript 2 is compiled into es6, so you may need to use babel or similar if you have to support older browsers. Do you compile assets locally or on heroku?

Comment: We compile assets on heroku. we doesn't support ie11, so i don't think that will be an issue either.